# How to turn a bezier curve into a shape?

Tags: inkscape, font-design, bezier-curve

Forgive me, I'm rather new to Graphic design. I'm currently making a font (in inkscape), and have been drawing the characters using bezier curves. An example can be seen below.
[image: Character plus path]

However, when I try to assign a keystroke to the shape using inkscape's built-in svg font editor, the font editor reads the curve as being filled, as can be seen below.
[image: Character filled in]

How can I make the bezier curve itself, plus it's width, into shape as opposed to just a bezier curve line, such that It gets read properly by the SVG font editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Path menu and choose Stroke to Path:

[image: Inkscape UI]

Comment: You, my friend, are a savior.

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers