# Clip or erase portions of a spirograph shape in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, windows-10

With Inkscape v0.92 on Windows 10 I have created a cool shape with the Extensions - Render - Spirograph tool (see the image below).  I would like to cut those portions of the spirograph so that I am only preserving the areas that are on the page. I am aware of how to cut shapes using Path-Difference and I can do that with simple shapes.  My problem is that when I use Path-Difference on my spirograph the resulting shape becomes a polygon and looses the spirograph lines.  How do I clip my spirograph and maintain the spirals?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The problem was solved with the stroke to path tool https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95042/how-to-turn-a-bezier-curve-into-a-shape

Comment: You don't need to use "stroke to path" and then use path-difference.  Learn about [how to use a clipping path](https://www.selfmadedesigner.com/cropping-inkscape/)

Comment: or you can cut the lines, and remove the cut-off parts with Path > Cut with a rectangle on top, and then select what you don't need with lasso selection (dragging a selection box).